# Sharing Facebook Page with FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui

I am implementing sharing feature on our web site.
I follow the document at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.4

Our code is as below:

```
var link_url = 'http://example.com/some/link';         // Works fine
link_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/<our_fan_page>';  // DOES NOT WORK

$("#btnShare").click(function(event){
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: link_url,
  }, function(response){
    if(response && response.post_id){
      alert("Thanks for sharing");
    }else{
      alert("Oop!");
    }
  });
});
```

It **works fine** for some link like http://example.com/some/link

The problem is: 
It **DOES NOT WORK** for our FB Page link (e.g, https://www.facebook.com/[our_page_name])

When clicking the 'Share' button, FB displays a dialog normally. But when I try by clicking 'Post to Facebook' button, it displays error

```
Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.
```

Does anybody have same problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: This works when I try it; is it still happening for you? \

Comment: Yes, the problem is still there. :(

Comment: Any success? This is still happening to me

Comment: @UriKlar: No, I can not solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

It's becoming an old post, but I saw it while looking for a fix so a solution to this problem could still benefit a few among us

Here is the JS code I use:

```
function fbs_click(width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Set borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Set title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
    u=location.href;
    t=document.title;
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
}
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=YOURLINK" onClick="return fbs_click(500, 300)" target="_blank" title="Share This on Facebook">
```

As you see here I do not use `FB.ui()`, but this trick to solve the issue.

To avoid having that issue:

> Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.

Make sure the link you'll share is not a localhost link (that was the only  reason I was getting that error).